# How to share over ethernet but not over wifi

Tags: macos, network, wifi, firewall

Running OSX 10.10.3

The office LAN is wired, the guest LAN is WiFi. I need to be on both at the same time.

I want to be able to accept connections from the office LAN, but I want to limit access to many of those services from the WiFi network. The clickable System Preferences for the firewall don't give me anything more powerful than "Allow Incoming Connections" which allows connections over all interfaces.

Where do I go to get more control over the firewall? Any tips for getting this config right?

This is not an issue of getting WiFi and Ethernet to work at the same time. They already work like I want them to. It's about firewalling-off services from certain interfaces, something that is not available in the standard System Preferences control panel.

Comment: The OS X firewall is based on a unix service that is configurable, however the configuration of firewalls is not simple. Could you give an example of what services you are trying to fix?

Comment: For instance... I want to keep afp/smb, ssh, and remote desktop open over Ethernet but blocked over WiFi. I'd like to keep a port 443 web server and the UDP ports necessary for handoff and continuity to work open over WiFi.

Comment: @unknowndomain, that link did it. Can't give answer credit to a comment though. :( Very much appreciated for the link.

Comment: @user2458080 i've rewritten the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X's firewall is very comprehensive, but it's GUI is limited, it can do what you want, but it's somewhat complex. I would try the following this guide http://www.techrepublic.com/article/configure-apples-built-in-network-firewall-with-icefloor/

For more advanced support you'd probably have more luck asking over on Server Fault (StackExchange) rather than here as it starts getting into the system and networking level stuff rather than OS X specifically.